# insert event to other calendars than my own primary one - 404 Not Found Error

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

i need to insert events to multiple calendars that don't belong to me (other users).
it doesn't have to be in one command...

To test the Google calendar API,  i used "insert" to add new events to my own calendar and it worked fine:

```
    // Create service from client
require_once "google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service.php";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
$client->setAccessToken(htmlspecialchars_decode(get_access_token()));

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary($bean->name);
$event->setLocation($bean->location);
$event->setDescription($bean->description);
...
...

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$createdEvent = $service->events->insert($user->google_cal_id_c, $event);
```

The problem is that when i operate the "insert" with my co-worker calendar id (that i took from his calendar settings) as the parameter and try to insert an event to his calendar,
i get "404 not found" Error.

**UPDATE:**

i notices that when the co-worker shares his calendar with mine, only then i can insert the event.
Does this mean all my 60 co-workers need to share their calendar with mine (the primary)? **cause i really don't want that!** 
can't i just add event to calendars that do not share theirs with me?

Comment: You need to have your coworkers authenticate your application, store the refreshtokens then you will have access to their calendars.

Comment: ohh, so each user that uses my software, will have to login to google, go through the authentication process, and through this authentication process, i'll get an Access token for him, that i will use to update his calendar? ok, will try it and keep you posted, thanks!

Comment: Its not Google Calendar api but it will at least help you understand the oauth2 flow.  http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Comment: yes yes , i have that already , just didn't know that i need access token for each calendar i want to insert :), thought it is per project.... will keep you posted.. thanks again!

Comment: its not each calendar its each user.  If the user has 10 calendars you will have access to write to all of them once they give you access.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you!! Can you write your comment as a reply so i can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get access tokens of each of your colleagues and use those for authentication. However, there are two main ways to go about inserting events into people's calendars when you don't want to ask for each of their's access tokens individually:

1. You can add them as attendees to your event, which will then send them an email and add it to their calendars
2. If you are all in the same domain and you are writing an app for that domain, you can create a service account (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and then use a domain-wide delegation of authority: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation (yes, the link is for drive API but the authentication works all the same between drive and calendar so just replace the drive bits with calendar)